# Multiple assignees for an entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

If I use the AssignRequest call to assign an owner to an entity, can I add multiple assignees to an entity, such as this below?

```
AssignRequest assign = new AssignRequest
{
Assignee = myUser,
Target = myEntity
};

AssignRequest assign = new AssignRequest
{
Assignee = myUser2,
Target = myEntity
};
```

Comment: An entity record can have only one owner at a time. If you assign it again, it will overwrite the existing.

Answer (score 0):

As Scorpion already commented a record can have only one owner.
The alternatives are to create a team containing the two users and assign the record to the team, or share the record if is suitable with your requirement.